# Loop through AWS Accounts in Lambda Python Function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a python script that loops through all of the AWS accounts we have and lists the EC2 instances in each one.

I want to turn it into an AWS Lambda function. But I can't figure out how to pull the AWS credentials that would allow me to list the servers in all the accounts.

How can I achieve this in AWS Lambda?

Comment: One way to do this is to create identically named IAM roles in each of the AWS accounts in question (each role should have a policy that allows it to list EC2 instances). Grant your lambda account permissions to assume that role in each of the AWS accounts (specify the lambda account ID in the assume role policy of each of the named roles). Then, inside your lambda, instantiate an STS credential provider for each account-specific role in question and then use that provider to make the EC2 SDK calls.

Comment: That being said, I suspect this *might* be a case of an XY problem. What is the ultimate goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to pull a list of EC2 instances in all of our AWS accounts. So, i need to find a way to access all the accounts without using a credentials file. Because I don't know how to store the creds in Lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a role with cross account permissions for ec2:ListInstances
2. Attach the role to the lambda function

Answer (score 0):

When you create lambda you have so specify a role
In IAM you can attach required permission to a lambda role.

If you want to use some specific set of credentials in a file, you can utilize AWS Systems Manager to retrieve credentials. 
Though, I would recommend role on lambda